# Apex trigger: Bulkification code problem

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

Is there a way to bulkify the below code? If we do a mass update of certain parts, its giving us too many queries.

```
for(Part__c p:Trigger.new){

    List<Sampling__c> sampList = [SELECT Part__c from Sampling__c where Part__c = :p.Id];
    if(sampList.size() > 0) {

        Part__c oldPart = Trigger.oldMap.get(p.Id);
        if( oldPart.Product__c != p.Product__c ) {
             p.adderror('This part number has a Quote-Part or Request associated with it and cannot be changed.');
        }
    }
}
```

What we are trying to check is; before updating part name in part__c object check if there is an entry in sampling object. If yes, then it should not allow the update on parts.

The mass update might have more than 100 records and the above code is breaking the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you will want to create a collection of Part__c IDs where a Sampling__c record contains a Part that is in the trigger.

```
//Create a collection of applicable part IDs
Set<ID> partIDs = New Set<ID>();

for(Sampling__c sample : [SELECT Part__c from Sampling__c where Part__c IN :trigger.new]){

    partIDs.add(sample.Part__c);
}

for(Part__c p:Trigger.new){

    //Check the collection here
    if(partIDs.contains(p.id)) {

        Part__c oldPart = Trigger.oldMap.get(p.Id);
        if( oldPart.Product__c != p.Product__c ) {
             p.adderror('This part number has a Quote-Part or Request associated with it and cannot be changed.');
        }
    }
}
```